# Prove divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1- \frac{\log n}n \right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I try to prove that this series diverges, the suggestion of the book is to show that $${\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}n\left( 1- \dfrac{\log n}{n} \right)^{n}} =1$$

For this, my attempt was to try to see that

$$
{\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \log \left[ n\left( 1- \dfrac{\log n}{n} \right)^{n} \right] }=0 $$

using that $\log x \leq x-1$ for $x=1-\dfrac{\log n}{n}$, already has a inequalities

$$\log n + n \log \left( 1-\dfrac{\log n}{n} \right)  \leq  \log n +n\left[  \left( 1-\dfrac{\log n}{n} \right)  -1\right] =0$$

but i can not find a lower bound  $c_ {n}$ for $\log n + n \log \left( 1-\dfrac{\log n}{n} \right) $ such that $c_ {n}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: You have $\log (1-t) = -(t + t^2/2 + t^3/3 + t^4/4 + \dotsb)$ estimate all terms $t^k/k$ for $k > 2$ by $t^k/2$, and you get a geometric series. That gives a good lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \left( 1- \dfrac{\log n}{n} \right)^{n}=e^{n\log\left( 1- \frac{\log n}{n}\right)}\sim_\infty e^{-\log n}=\frac{1}{n}$$
and the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent. Conclude.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you see that $n\log\left( 1- \frac{\log n}{n}\right)\sim_\infty -\log n$?

Comment: Use that $\log(1-x)\sim_0 -x$.

Comment: And this is true by L'Hopital?

Comment: Yes or by the Taylor series.

Comment: By using this $log(1-x) = -x - \frac{x^2}{2} -\frac{x^3}{3}-\dots$, right?

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.